# How Can I Align Double Digits in a html Numbered List?

Tags: html, html-lists

How Can I align Double Digits in a html Numbered List?. i have an ordered list listing 14 items. In all browsers except ie7 it is working correctly. But in IE7 seems to be removing the space after double-digit numbers in ordered lists.

```
<ol>
<li>aaa</li>
<li>bbb</li>
<li>ccc</li>
 .....

</ol/>
```

The output in IE7 is like

1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc
....
10.kkk
11.lll

I don't know why it is removing the space after the dot(.) from 10 onwards.
Anybody please suggest me a solution

Comment: there seems to be an extra markup in your HTML . it should be </ol> not </ol/> .

Answer (score 0):

In css, you could try something along the lines of

```
ol{
  left-padding: 2em;
}
ol li{
  left-padding:0.5em;
}
```

It might let you keep the spacing consistent between the number and the content of the `li`.
I haven't seen anyone alter the alignment of the numbers in an `<ol>` in IE7.

Alternatively, if it's not a big pain you could add the numbers manually, something like

```
<ul>
  <li><em>1.</em>Apple</li>
  <li><em>2.</em>Banana</li>
  ...
  <li><em>14.</em>Orange</li>
</ul>
```

And use css like:

```
li{
  list-style-type: none;
  clear: left;
}
li em{
  float: left;
  width: 2em;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  text-align: right;
}
```

With that, you would have the effect you want.